# PHP with REST web services

Tags: php, rest

There is a REST web service that already exists. There is only one user: admin. Once I enter the admin credentials while logging in, a token is generated internally for security purposes and then from that once that token is validated, I am suppose to enter the homepage.

I have added the PHP part of the code for a simple login that I have done already. I would like to know how and where do I add and invoke the token part for the authentication, based on the above situation.

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

/* Check Login form submitted */    
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    /* Define username and associated password array */
    $logins = array('admin' => 'Kcuf94!');

    /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
    $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
    $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

    /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
    if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
        /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
        $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
        header("location:Homepagedisplay.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
        $echo="<span style='color:black'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That seems like an overly-complicated way to do that... if that login is static, set them as CONST values, or just do your conditional statements directly against those string values.

Can you be more specific about "a token is generated internally"? How is it generated? Where and how is it stored? 

For clarity, are you saying you log in using the code above, and then from there, you'd like to now call a web service that requires a token for authentication? Most web service calls allow you to pass a token along with a method call at the same time.